# Is there a way to verify a file contains a class, interface or function before including it for FileReflection()?

Tags: php, regex, reflection

We've got a tree traversal loop running which identifies PHP files all well and good, but for each file we run PHP's `FileReflection` against it which requires the file to be *included* first. For the purpose of this script, we're only interested in files that contain `Class`, `Interface` or `Function` declarations.

**Is there a way to identify whether a file includes a `Class`, `Interface` or `Function` declaration before running `include()` on it?**

My guess is that it'll have to be a regex against the `get_file_contents()` value, but I was hoping for a more elegant (read: consistent and reliable) solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself, for those interested...

`$tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents($file,TRUE));
$valid = FALSE;
foreach($tokens as $token) {
    if (isset($token[0]) && in_array($token[0],array(T_CLASS,T_FUNCTION,T_INTERFACE))) {
        $valid = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$valid) { return NULL; }
include_once $file;
$reflection = new FileReflection($file);
...`